# How to call controller function from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, web-applications

Creating a web app using mvc and codeigniter. In the view, on the click of a button it calls a javascript method. This method should take the source of 3 images as parameters, and pass them to a controller method. The controller method then turns them into a single $record and passes it to a function in the model, which will then insert the record contents into a database.

View button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assemble bot" onclick="insertAssembled()"></input>
```

Javascript function:

```
function assemble(var head, var body, var legs) {
    var head = document.getElementById("HeadImage".src);
    var body = document.getElementById("BodyImage".src);
    var legs = document.getElementById("FeetImage".src);
    // call controller function here, passing head body and legs
}
```

Controller method:

```
    public function insertAssembled($head, $body, $legs) {
        //Build record and send to saveBot       
        $record['id'] = 1;
        $record['head'] = $head;
        $record['body'] = $body;
        $record['legs'] = $legs;
        $this->Robotsdata->saveBot($record);
   }
```

Model method (very rough, help not needed just trying to pass parameters):

```
public function saveBot($record) {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root@localhost","");
    mysql_select_db("factory", $con);
    $bot_id = $_POST['id'];
    $bot_head = $_POST['head'];
    $bot_body = $_POST['body'];
    $bot_legs = $_POST['legs'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `factory`.`assembledbots` ('id', 'head', 'body', 'legs') "
            . "VALUES ('$bot_id', '$bot_head', '$bot_body', '$bot_legs');";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Comment: please read about SQL injections

Comment: ajax is your  only  friend for the situation

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass your datas using ajax if you've included the jQuery library :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Path/To/YourController.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        head: head, //You'll get it with $_POST['head']
        body: body, //You'll get it with $_POST['body']
        legs: legs  //You'll get it with $_POST['legs']
    },
})
.done(function(data) {
    // Do what you want in case of success
})
.fail(function(err) {
    //Do what you want incase of error
});
```

Comment: And using ajax, would I even need a controller function?

Comment: Yes, you should send the data from your controller to your model like you do usually.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using ajax. Also, in your model, try using CI's Query Builder Class (Active Record) so your queries are safe and to avoid SQL injections.

**javascript**

```
function assemble(var head, var body, var legs) {
   var head = document.getElementById("HeadImage".src);
   var body = document.getElementById("BodyImage".src);
   var legs = document.getElementById("FeetImage".src);

   //ajax
   //you post variables
   var fields = {
      head  : head,
      body  : body,
      legs  : legs,
      submit_a: true
   };

   $.ajax({
     url: 'domain/controller/insertAssembled',
     type: 'POST',
     data: fields,
     dataType:'JSON',
     success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
     }
   });
}
```

**controller**

```
public function insertAssembled() 
{

  if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) { // just additional, to make sure request is from ajax
    if ($this->input->post('submit_a')) {
        $record['id'] = 1;
        $record['head'] = $this->input->post('head');
        $record['body'] = $this->input->post('body');
        $record['legs'] = $this->input->post('legs');

        // to model
        $this->Robotsdata->saveBot($record);

        // return to view
        echo json_encode(array("error"=>false));
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**model**

```
public function saveBot($record) 
{
  if ($record) {

    $save_fields = array(
        'id'   => $record['id'],
        'head' => $record['head'],
        'body' => $record['body'],
        'legs' => $record['legs']
    );
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $save_fields);

    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but currently I'm unable to get this working, does 'submit_a' need to be changed to something specific to my program?

Comment: @Bobbis you may change it depends to you. submit_a is just an identifier to make sure it is really that specific POST variable from that specific ajax request. Just make sure when you rename, the variable name has to be the same from the ajax to the one you will be calling in your controller. What errors have you encountered now?